# How to pass request variables/data from a middleware to another function with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I want to verify the jwt token of an user with a middleware. So i have this middleware:

```js
const authorized = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const token = req.header("token")
    if(!token){
        return res.send("No token, authorization denied!")
    }
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
    if(!decoded){
        return res.send("Token is not valid!")
    }
    //req.user = decoded THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO PASS DATA to the CONTROLLER function
    next()
}
```

Doing that i can get the user that made the request and let him do stuff next..
But using Typescript the problem is that user on `req.user` isn't defined. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define or let's say basically extend the Express request type and then add your own variable/object called `user`.

To do so, create a file called `index.d.ts` inside a new type folder, which you can create in your source (src) folder. It should look like this:

`src/types/express/index.d.ts`

[image]

The content of the file should be

```js
declare global {
    namespace Express {
        // tslint:disable-next-line:interface-name
        interface Request {
            user: string;
        }
    }
}
```

Open your `tsconfig.json` or typescript config file and add this types folder path in `typeRoots`.

```js
"typeRoots": [
   "node_modules/@types",
   "src/@types"
],
```

Now you can access the `user` variable anywhere in the project as long as you import request from "express", for example

```js
import {NextFunction, Request, Response} from "express";

export const getUser = () => {
    return async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        const user = req.user;
        // do something with user
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! and another question... for using process.env i must declare this interface `declare var process : {
    env: {
        [key: string]: string
    }
}` is there another way to do it? or where can i declare it globally?

Comment: for environment variables, you need to create a file called `environment.d.ts` at the root of your project (where package.json sits), and the content of the file should be similar to https://pastebin.com/pu5jtUQ7